# Is there a limit on the size of std::set::iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, dereference, stdset

I have a std::set of strings and I want to iterate over them, but the iterator is behaving differently for different sizes of set. Given below is the code snippet that I'm working on:

```
int test(set<string> &KeywordsDictionary){
    int keyword_len = 0;
    string word;
    set<string>::iterator iter;

    cout << "total words in the database : " << KeywordsDictionary.size() << endl;

    for(iter=KeywordsDictionary.begin();iter != KeywordsDictionary.end();iter++) {

        cout << *iter;

        word = *iter;
        keyword_len = word.size();

        if(keyword_len>0)
            Dosomething();
        else
            cout << "Length of keyword is <= 0" << endl;
    }
    cout << "exiting test program"  << endl;
}
```

The code is working properly & `*iter` is being dereferenced & assigned to `word` until the size of `KeywordsDictionary` is around 15000. However when the size of `KeywordsDictionary` increases beyond 15000,

1. the print statement `cout << *iter;` is printing all the contents of `KeywordsDictionary` correctly.
2. but the pointer to the iterator `*iter` is not being dereferenced & not being assigned to `word`. `word` is just being an empty string.

**EDIT:** And the output of the program is :

```
total words in the database : 22771
�z���AAAADAAIIABABBABLEABNABOUTACACCEPTEDACCESSACCOUNT...
Length of keyword is <= 0
exiting test program
```

So basically, I'm guessing the loop is executing only once.

Comment: `std::set<T>::iterator` is a fixed size, regardless of the size of the contents held in the `T` object.

Comment: Please present a complete example that demonstrates the problem, copied and pasted from something you actually compiled and ran.

Comment: You don' seem to have a newline at the end of printing the string (`cout << *iter;`), so all the strings will be printed one after another on the same line? Is that what you see?

Comment: I think the problem is because of non-ASCII values such as : `�z���` and assigning them to `word` which is of string type whose range is only char type and ASCII values. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: and whenever its reading a non-ASCII value, the string variable `word` is being empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare keyword_len as

```
std::string::size_type keyword_len = 0;
```

instead of

```
int keyword_len = 0;
```

Comment: If the threshold for problems really is as low as 15000, this seems unlikely culprit.